# Linq Find the most recurring record

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq

I have a rent a car project.
[This is the table where I keep the rented vehicles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGwN7.png)
I want to find the most rented vehicle in this table. How can I do this?
So I want to find the most mentioned car Id in the table
[[I have to do it with context architecture. How can I do this with c # linq?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sze4x.png)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sze4x.png)

Comment: Please read [ask]. Not only because you shouldn't use images as a replacement for text, but also because you could give some more details. For one, it isn't clear which type of LINQ you're using. (Entity Framework? Which version?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to find the most rented vehicle in this table.

So basically you want to find out how many times car 5 is rented, and how many times car 6 is rented, etc, and keep the carId with the highest rental count.

As you are working with a database, my advice would be to use GroupBy to make groups of rentals that have the same CarId, and then keep the group that has the most number of rentals = order by descending count and take the first.

We'll use the [overload of Queryable.GroupBy that has a parameter resultSelector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.groupby?view=net-5.0#System_Linq_Queryable_GroupBy__3_System_Linq_IQueryable___0__System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_System_Func___0___1___System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_System_Func___1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0____2___), so we can select the number of rentals in the group as result.

```
// make groups of CarRentals that have the same CarId:
var mostRentedCarId = dbContext.CarRentals.GroupBy(carRental => carRental.CarId,

// parameter resultSelector: for every CarId and all CarRentals that have this CarId,
// make one new object
(carId, carRentalsWithThisCarId) => new
{
    CarId = carId,
    RentalCount = carRentalsWithThisCarId.Count(),
})

// order the groupBy result by descending rentalCount and take the first or default:
.OrderByDescending(groupByResult => groupByResult.RentalCount)
.FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

if you mean that you want to find the sql query string for that question u can use the count() to count how many times the id of a specific car is repeated. And since you want the most rented car you can use somthing like this:`select top 1 count(CarId) from tableName  group by CarId  order by count(CarId) desc`
this should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a query like the below, or use the approach as suggested by Abdelghafour Lahrache.

```
SELECT MAX(CarCount)
FROM
(
   SELECT COUNT(CarId) AS CarCount
   FROM YourTableName
   GROUP BY CarId
) CarIdCounter
```

Comment: How should I write this in c # linq?

Comment: How does your code look like so far? From your original question it was not clear you wanted to solve it using Linq.

Comment: I updated the question, sorry I asked incompletely